# ng-repeat refusing to execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have my Javascript (Angular custom directive) as follows:

```
var addedSubject = function($rootScope){
   return{
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl:'/static/html/marks_app/directives/added_subject_item.html',
      replace:true,
      scope:{
      },
      controller:["$scope", function($scope){
          $scope.mySubjects = $rootScope.allSubjects;
      console.log($scope.mySubjects);
  }]
  };
 };
 marksApp.directive('addedSubjectDirective', ["$rootScope",addedSubject]);
```

My HTML as follows:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form_body sub_results">
                    <div id="search_module_head" class="form_panels">
                        <div id="search_univ" >
                            <select id="form_sub_sel" autofocus form="form_sub_eval">
                                <option disabled selected>Select University</option>
                                <option value="ufs">University of the Free State</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div id="search_code" class="form_panels">
                            <input type"text" id="search_code_input" ng-model="subFilter" placeholder="Enter Subject Code"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search_results">
                        <div class="search_results_head">
                            <p>Search Results</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="search_results_content">
                            <ul>
                              <search-result-list-item
                                ng-repeat="varsitySub in allUnivSubjects | searchFor:subFilter"
                                varsity-subject="varsitySub">
                              </search-result-list-item>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="added_sub_list">
                    <div class="added_sub_list_head">
                      <p>
                        Added Subjects
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="added_sub_list_body">
                      <ul>
                          <added-subject-directive ng-repeat="addedSub in mySubjects">
                          </added-subject-directive>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
             </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that when I run the code with ng-repeat on the HTML for the directive (added-subject-directive), the code is refusing to work. Its not showing anything on the screen and also its not logging anything I try to log from the Javascript of the directive. However, when I remove ng-repeat, the code executes as expected (without **ALL** the required output though due to absence of ng-repeat). I have pulled out all my hair so can anyone please kindly help me to try and understand what I could possibly be doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things. `ngRepeat` is a terminal directive. With a terminal directive the current priority will be the last set of directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is undefined). Note that expressions and other directives used in the directive's template will also be excluded from execution.

`ngRepeat` also has a priority of 1000. When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is `undefined`. The default priority is `0`.

Add a higher priority to your directive to ensure it runs first.

```
var addedSubject = function($rootScope){
   return{
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl:'/static/html/marks_app/directives/added_subject_item.html',
      replace:true,
      priority: 1001, // added higher priority than ngRepeat
      scope:{
      },
      controller:["$scope", function($scope){
          $scope.mySubjects = $rootScope.allSubjects;
      console.log($scope.mySubjects);
  }]
  };
 };
 marksApp.directive('addedSubjectDirective', ["$rootScope",addedSubject]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I am now getting some movement in my code. The console.log($scope.mySubjects); inside the custom directive is now executing and showing output in the console, something it was not doing. However, there is still no output on the screen. Any other pointers you could give?

Comment: Without a fiddle demonstrating the issue it is difficult to go any further. Another solution may be putting the ngRepeat in the template referenced by the directive rather than as an attribute on the directive.

Comment: I appreciate your help. The solution of putting the ngRepeat inside the template did the job. Not sure if its a fix but it worked out. Thank you once again.